# PDF24 is in error state although it claims to be ready as Printer

Tags: windows, printing, pdf-generation

My client is making me use [PDF24](https://en.pdf24.org/) as converter to PDF which works as printer. It stopped working without any obvious reason, the Windows error message popup is not too helpful:

> **Printer is an error state**
>
> 'PDF24 PDF' is in an error state.

I found as [official solution](https://help.pdf24.org/en/questions/question/printer-in-error-state/) which says

> Hi, ensure, that the PDF24 Windows Service is running. If this service is stopped, then the PDF printer will not work and no print jobs will be redirected to the printing user. This is normally the cause, if the PDF printer fails to work.

When checking for such a service by running `services.msc` I do not find any service with PDF24 within the name which I could restart. My group policy does not allow to reinstall the printer, and a reboot (which the IT service suggested) did not help either. **Does anybody has an idea how to start this

ominous service?**

**EDIT**: I also found https://help.pdf24.org/en/questions/question/pdf24-startup-failure/ which suggests to do `net start pdf24` with admin rights in command line, but `The service name is invalid.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDF24 is not available, then reinstall the service. To do this, open a command line and execute the following:

```
pdf24.exe -install -start
```

Comment: Fine ;-) and if you have more questions, ask me, I'm the PDF24 developer.